# Changed nib File to a OPGL ES View, Buttons don't work

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, opengl-es, rendering

Hy,

There is no problmen with changing the nib but when I'm in the nib-File with the OPGL ES view my buttons that are integrated in this view won't work. When I press one the application crashes.

This is the Code how I change the View to the Second Nib:

```
- (IBAction)drawEAGLView:(id)sender {

NSArray* nibViews =  [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"settingsViewController" owner:self options:nil];
EAGLView* glView = [ nibViews objectAtIndex: 1];
self.view = glView;
[glView startAnimation];}
```

The Animation is working    .

This is the Code of the ViewController where the Button is declared:

SettingsViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface SettingsViewController : NSObject {

    IBOutlet UIButton *wowButton;
}
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIButton *wowButton;

- (IBAction)wowButtonPressed:(id)sender;

int testvarAnimation;
int animNext;


@end
```

SettingsViewController.m:

```
#import "SettingsViewController.h"
@implementation SettingsViewController
@implementation SettingsViewController
@synthesize wowButton;


- (IBAction)wowButtonPressed:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"TOUCHED");
    //testvarAnimation = 1;
    animNext =1;

}

- (void)dealloc {
    [wowButton release];
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Here I show you how I connected the Functions and the Outlets:
http://s3.imgimg.de/uploads/screenshotConna91ea645png.png

Please tell me If you need more informations.

Thanks

Comment: You're going to have to provide more information than that. I can only suggest you study the OpenGL ES sample project that XCode creates and try to see what's different between it and yours.

Comment: Hy sorry that i didn't provide enough information but I have changed my approach to solve this problem, but I don't know how to edit my Question, or should i post a new one ??

Comment: Ok I managed to edit this Question =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the right solution for this problem:

First you have to create a parnet object of your view you want to be shown as first.
You need to do this in the header file of the second view.

```
//
//  SettingsViewController.h
//  NeheTutorial2
//
//  Created by Global Sound on 05.04.11.
//  Copyright 2011 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class EAGLView;
@class mobilesynthViewController;

@interface SettingsViewController : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UIButton *wowButton;
    IBOutlet UIButton *optiButton;

    EAGLView *glView;
    //mobilesynthViewController *mViewController;
    mobilesynthViewController *parent;
}
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIButton *wowButton;
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIButton *optiButton;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet EAGLView *glView;
//@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet mobilesynthViewController *mViewController;

@property (nonatomic, retain) mobilesynthViewController *parent;

- (IBAction)wowButtonPressed:(id)sender;

- (IBAction)optiButtonPressed:(id)sender;

int testvarAnimation;
int animNext;
int musicOn;
int isAnimating;
float zaehler;


@end
```

Now in the implemetaion File you need to add the parent object to your function:

```
#import "SettingsViewController.h"
#import "EAGLView.h"
//#import "mobilesynthViewController.h"


@implementation SettingsViewController

@synthesize wowButton, optiButton, glView;//,mViewController;
@synthesize parent;

- (IBAction)wowButtonPressed:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"TOUCHED");
    [parent startThread];
    [parent showbButtonStop];
    testvarAnimation = 0;
    animNext =1;
    //musicOn =1;
}

- (IBAction)optiButtonPressed:(id)sender{

    NSLog(@"OPTIONS ON");
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [parent showbButton];



    //mobilesynthViewController *aRootViewController = [[mobilesynthViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"mobilesynthViewContoller" bundle:nil];
    //[self setRootViewController:aRootViewController];
    //[aRootViewController release]; 


    //mobilesynthViewController *mViewController = [[mobilesynthViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"mobilesynthViewController" bundle:nil];
    //[[self.view superview] addSubview:mViewController.view];
    //self.view = mViewController;

    //CGRect rect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
    //mViewController = [[mobilesynthViewController alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y, rect.size.width, rect.size.height)];
    //self.view = mViewController;

}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    glView.animationInterval = 1.0 / 60.0;
    [glView startAnimation];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
/*

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}
*/
- (void)dealloc {
    [wowButton release];
    [optiButton release];
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

In my case I'm calling a other function in the main View of my program. When the button in the second view is pressed the function in the first view is called through the the parent object

```
[parent startThread];
```

Again the startThread methode was declerated in another view.

I hope I could help you.

Answer (score 0):

Hy I solved my problem, I rewrote my drawEAGLView Methode:

```
- (IBAction)drawEAGLView:(id)sender {

    SettingsViewController *sViewController = [[SettingsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SettingsViewController" bundle:nil];
        [[self.view superview] addSubview:sViewController.view];

    }
```

I also corrected my SettingsViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@class EAGLView;

@interface SettingsViewController : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UIButton *wowButton;

    EAGLView *glview;
}
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIButton *wowButton;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet EAGLView *glView;

- (IBAction)wowButtonPressed:(id)sender;

int testvarAnimation;
int animNext;


@end
```

And last but not least I changed my SettingsViewController.m:

```
#import "SettingsViewController.h"
#import "EAGLView.h"



@implementation SettingsViewController

@synthesize wowButton, glView;


- (IBAction)wowButtonPressed:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"TOUCHED");
    //testvarAnimation = 1;
    animNext =1;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    glView.animationInterval = 1.0 / 60.0;
    [glView startAnimation];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
- (void)dealloc {
    [wowButton release];
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

I also changed my Nib file. I removed the ViewController and set the type of the File's Owner to my viewController named "SettingsViewController". I connected the File's Owner Outlet view with the EAGLView and the button with the SettingsViewControllers wowButtonPressed Method

I hope I could help also someone else,

Thanks

Comment: Hy it's me again
I found a better way to solve this problem, because this solution crashes the app on the device. I will poste the better one on the 7.May.2011. I'm sorry for this but I'm really stressed, soon I have my final exams at school!